# Can I make QSettings settings for 2 or more applications?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qsettings

There are 2 applications:

1. creates a file somewhere, and
2. should go along some path and pick up the contents of the file.

Can I in the first application specify the path to the file in QSettings, and the second to take this path from the registry and go through it to the file?

Please tell me a simple example.

Comment: you could use IPC approach. whether it will be TCP\IP or D-Bus protocol (only in linux) or shared memory

Comment: If these two applications are on same machine you can use [IPC](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ipc.html) as most suitable, if your applications are on different machines or will later be on different machines it is better to use Tcp/Ip approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot suggest a cross-platform method based on registry, but want to show another ways.

---

### Method 1 (based on common ini file)

1. Store the path in some common ini file, for example in `<some_common_path>/settings_common.ini`. Both applications shall have access to the file:

**App 1 (Writer)**

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

#include <QSettings>
#include <QDebug>

#include <QThread>

const QString CommonSettingsFilePath = "c:/temp/settings_common.ini";
const QString CommonKey = "common/path";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    for(;;)
    {
        static int it = 0;

        QString pathString = QString("path_%1").arg(it++);

        QSettings settings(CommonSettingsFilePath, QSettings::IniFormat);
        settings.setValue(CommonKey, pathString);

        QThread::sleep(1);
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

**App 2 (Reader)**

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

#include <QSettings>
#include <QDebug>

#include <QThread>

const QString CommonSettingsFilePath = "c:/temp/settings_common.ini";
const QString CommonKey = "common/path";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    for (;;)
    {    
        QSettings settings(CommonSettingsFilePath, QSettings::IniFormat);
        QString pathString = settings.value(CommonKey, "").toString();

        qDebug() << "Path read from ini =" << pathString;

        QThread::sleep(2);
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Possible output of the App 2:

```
Path read from ini = "path_6"
Path read from ini = "path_8"
Path read from ini = "path_9"
Path read from ini = "path_11"
...
```

---

### Method 2 (based on Inter-process communication)

[IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) using [Qt Remote Objects API](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtremoteobjects-index.html):
App1 is [Source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtremoteobjects-source.html#source), App2 (reader) will be [Replica](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtremoteobjects-replica.html#replica), the path is a property.

*Only the main points are shown.*

In both App1 and App2 .pro files add `remoteobjects` module:

```
QT  += core remoteobjects ...
```

**path.rep** file:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QString>

class Path
{
    PROP(QString path);
};
```

In App1 pro:

```
REPC_SOURCE = path.rep
```

App1 class:

```
#include "rep_path_source.h"

class CommonPath : public PathSimpleSource
{
    Q_OBJECT
};
```

Then in App1:

```
CommonPath sourcePath;

QRemoteObjectHost sourceNode(QUrl("local:path")); // create host node
sourceNode.enableRemoting(&sourcePath); // enable remoting/sharing

...

sourcePath.setPath("some_path_aaa");
```

In App2 pro:

```
REPC_REPLICA = path.rep
```

In App2 furthermore:

```
#include "rep_path_replica.h"

QSharedPointer<PathReplica> replica;

QRemoteObjectNode repNode; // create remote object node
repNode.connectToNode(QUrl("local:path")); // connect with remote host node

replica.reset(repNode.acquire<PathReplica>()); // acquire replica of source from host node

replica->waitForSource();

...

qDebug() << replica->path();
```

**Of course you can distribute all the necessary data in this way, not just the path.**